# Excel- IF ELSE Statements

Tags: excel

Trying to learn excel things. Could someone please help me understand how to write IF / ELSE statements in Excel? I get lost when dealing with logical operators and running through multiple else if conditions.

The example I am working with is as follows:

```
IF (A1 == NULL)
        B1 = ""
    ELSE IF (A1 != NULL) AND (C1 == NULL)
        B1 = (A1 - Today's Date)
    ELSE IF (A1 != NULL) AND (C1 != NULL)
        B1 = (A1 - C1)
    ELSE
        ERROR
```

A1- if not null, will contain a date value (e.g. 2/28/2016)

B1- an integer representing the number of days passed between two dates

C1- if not null, will contain a date value

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What have you researched? Generally, you would just "piggy back" the `If` statement. `=If(A1="Man",[do something if true],If(A1="woman",[do something if not man, but is woman],if(A1="thing",[do something if not man, nor woman, but thing],if(And(a1="Man",a1="woman"),[do someting if both man and woman],...`

Comment: It's not the answer, as I think you're asking in general, which you can find online...but for your example, it'd be (entered in cell `B1`): `=If(A1="","",if(and(A1<>"",C1=""),A1-today(),if(And(A1<>"",C1<>""),A1-C1,"Error"),"Error")`  ...or pretty close to that. AFAIK there's no real `NULL` in Excel, so the blank cell (`""`) should work.

Comment: @BruceWayne your outer IF has too many arguments. The last Error is not needed and you need another closing bracket to close all three IF statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo code:

```
IF (A1 == NULL)
        B1 = ""
    ELSE IF (A1 != NULL) AND (C1 == NULL)
        B1 = (A1 - Today's Date)
    ELSE IF (A1 != NULL) AND (C1 != NULL)
        B1 = (A1 - C1)
    ELSE
        ERROR
```

translated into an Excel formula, where the formula would live in cell B1

```
=if(A1="","",if(C1="",A1-today(),A1-C1))
```

I argue that since the FALSE branch of the outermost IF statement only fires if A1 is not null, you don't need to test for A1 a second time.

In the same vein, C1 is either null or not, so no need for another nested if and there really is no case where the Else would return an error.

Comment: Way less complicated than I was making it- THANK YOU!

Here's what I ended with:

=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(ISBLANK(C1),DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d"),(A1-C1)*-1)

Answer (score 0):

Excel's IF statement works like C or Java's condition statemnt:

(test condition)? run this if true: run this if false

In Excel, its:

IF(test condition, run this if true, run this if false)

so it takes 3 parameters. It gets complicated if you've got recursive if's because that would have to be nested within the outermost IF statemnt.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation of the parameters. Very helpful.